# Different training results on different machines?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, random-generation

I'm running the exact same script (Python, TF and Keras) on my Macbook and on a DGX Server.

I've tried once to verify if I can get the exact same result on both machines by fixing every seed of every random number generator(This was explained in a post about reproducibility). It turned out that I couldn't even reproduce the same result on the same machine. With some more major changes this might could be accomplished, but I didn't tried further.

Currently I'm trying to optimize some hyperparamters and the number of neurons. Thats when I noticed that the DGX and my Macbook behave often quite differently. Is there a reason for this? Maybe something with the hardware or the random number generators? It might just look like this because I haven't carried out enough tests (only about 3 runs with the same settings, in total about 18 runs).

Comment: Have you looked into the possibility of a bug in one of the randomizing functions that you are using? Perhaps it is supposed to use the random seed but due to a bug doesn't? You might be able to isolate that possibility by running each function that uses random numbers alone on a simple test dataset and verify that they are always reproducible.

Comment: @Tripartio Well that could be an explanation. Shouldn't one be able to assume that Keras and Tensorflow have their random number well implemented? Otherwise I have to test every function in all my future projects (?)

Comment: it is safer to assume that any major and extremely active ongoing platform will always accidentally introduce bugs, but you never know when. I don't know if a bug is the cause of your problem, but you should certainly never rule that out as a possibility. If all the specific functions you are using have not been updated for at least one year of heavy use, then you might reasonably feel safe to assume that it is unlikely that there would be any new bugs.

Comment: They are all quite basic and well used. I highly assume this can't be the difference.

Comment: Can you give more details? E.g. software versions etc. Do you use the same floating point precision in both cases?